# How do I generate a HMAC code?

Tags: 8

How can I generate a [HMAC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash-based_message_authentication_code) code in Drupal 8?

In plain PHP, I would use [`hash_hmac()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.hash-hmac.php). Is there a more specific method/function, in Drupal 8?

Answer (score 4):

You could still `hash_hmac()` in Drupal 8. Drupal 8 has a static function that returns the HMAC given a couple of data and key arguments ([`Drupal\Component\Utility\Crypt::hmacBase64()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Component%21Utility%21Crypt.php/function/Crypt%3A%3AhmacBase64/8.2.x)). The differences are the following.

- `Crypt::hmacBase64()` returns the Base64-encoded HMAC value
- `Crypt::hmacBase64()` replaces some characters to make the string safe to use in URLs
- `Crypt::hmacBase64()` raises an exception when the arguments are not using the expected datatype

If you don't need to encode the HMAC value in Base64, or to pass the HMAC value in URLs, you can use `hash_hmac()`. You could consider `Drupal\Component\Utility\Crypt::hmacBase64()` a wrapper around two PHP functions, since its code is the following one.

```php
if (!is_scalar($data) || !is_scalar($key)) {
  throw new \InvalidArgumentException('Both parameters passed to \Drupal\Component\Utility\Crypt::hmacBase64 must be scalar values.');
}

$hmac = base64_encode(hash_hmac('sha256', $data, $key, TRUE));
return str_replace(['+', '/', '='], ['-', '_', ''], $hmac);
```

Answer (score 2):

It implemented in Drupal,
[How to Generate HMAC in drupal 7](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!bootstrap.inc/function/drupal_hmac_base64/7.x)

Drupal 7

**Drupal 7** 
presents wrapper functions to get shorter, base-64 encoded hashes to use in URLs, etc. See:

```
drupal_hash_base64($data)
drupal_hmac_base64($data, $key)
```

**Drupal 8**

For Drupal 8 these have been moved to a utility class:

```
\Drupal\Component\Utility\Crypt::hashBase64($data)
\Drupal\Component\Utility\Crypt::hmacBase64($data, $key)
```

for more details follow [this link](https://www.drupal.org/writing-secure-code/hash-functions)